# PostGIS point st_within() polygon = false

Tags: postgis

so geoserver shows me a red dot within a blue polygon, i thought postgis can tell me that fact by query. i tried the following statements without success, can anyone tell me what i did wrong?

```
select

    -- within on geometry with srid
    ST_Within(
        st_geometryfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)', 4326)
        ,
        st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))', 4326)
    ),

    -- within on geometry with srid, swap arguments
    ST_Within(
        st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))', 4326)
        ,
        st_geometryfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)', 4326)
    ),

    -- within on geometry without srid
    ST_Within(
        st_geometryfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)')
        ,
        st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))')
    ),

    -- within on geometry without srid, swap arguments
    ST_Within(
        st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))')
        ,
        st_geometryfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)')
    ),

    -- contains on geometry with srid
    ST_Contains(
        st_geometryfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)', 4326)
        ,
        st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))', 4326)
    ),

    -- contains on geometry with srid, swap arguments
    ST_Contains(
        st_geometryfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))', 4326)
        ,
        st_geometryfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)', 4326)
    ),

    -- intersects on geography
    ST_Intersects(
        st_geographyfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)')
        ,
        st_geographyfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))')
    ),

    -- intersects on geography, swap arguments
    ST_Intersects(
        st_geographyfromtext('POLYGON((9 52,9.2 52,9.1 52.1066357,9 52))')
        ,
        st_geographyfromtext('point(9.05 52.25)')
    )
```

Comment: perhaps it *isn't* in the polygon :)

Answer (score 6):

Yup... it isn't in the polygon[image: outside]

By the way, you can simply visualize WKT from QGIS using QuickWKT plugin. That way you can do sanity check like this one.